# Is it possible to start debugging Gallio test case in MS VC# 2010 by "Debug \ Start debugging" command?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, unit-testing, debugging, gallio

I have dll with tests for gallio.

I specified in "Project Properties \ Debug \ Start External Command":  Gallio.Echo.exe

I also specfied "Command Line Arguments": /runner:IsolatedAppDomain Full\Path\To\My\Dll\With\Tests.dll

I specified /runner:IsolatedAppDomain because I want to run tests in the same process which should allow MS VS debugger to automatically connect to tests which are in the same process as Gallio.Echo.exe. (At least for C++ projects it works)

When I execute "Debug \ Start debugging" I obtain the following warning:

```
[warning] File 'Tests.dll' is not supported by any installed test framework.
  It will be ignored.
        Location: Full\Path\To\My\Dll\With\Tests.dll
[ignored] Unsupported Tests.dll
Detected a probable test framework assembly version mismatch.
Referenced test frameworks: 'MbUnit, Version=3.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=eb9cfa67ee6ab36e'.
Supported test frameworks: 'MbUnit, Version=3.3.0.0'.
```

I installed lastest gallio version GallioBundle-3.3.458.0.

It seems that Gallio should have the same framework version as Tests.dll.
But Gallio is 2.0, and I use 4.0.

How to fix the issue?

P.S. Now I use `TestDriven.Net`. But it is not exactly what I want, it is not convenient to use when I work with one test case but several source files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`TestDriven.Net` has option in context menu "Repeat Test Run"